# How can I get help with testing conundrums and mocking/unit-testing newbie ignorance

Tags: discussion

I had a longer question written up that was similar to this, but included my real question.  But I wanted to start more conservatively in finding the correct forum for it...

Where should one ask questions of the sort "how do I isolate and test a specific part of my software system that does not appear to me to lend itself to mocking or unit testing?"?  Is there an appropriate forum within the SE ecosystem for getting help with targeted testing strategies regarding a specific complex system?

My hesitation comes from the fact that my question would seem to solicit "opinion based" answers.  I'm pretty sure there won't be "a RIGHT answer" to my issue.

PS: btw, I had trouble in even picking an appropriate tag for this question.

Answer (score 6):

Of all the SE sites, this is definitely the best. Your hesitation is warranted, and shows an understanding of how to ask SE questions I wish was shared by all users! Bravo!

You may rest assured such questions are welcome on this and other sites. Robert Cartaino wrote an excellent piece nearly 10 years ago on this exact subject, titled [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and like a fine vintage has only got better with age.

It can be summarized as

> Great subjective questions:
>
> inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
>
> tend to have long, not short, answers
>
> have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
>
> invite sharing experiences over opinions
>
> insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
>
> are more than just mindless social fun

To be sure, there is a higher bar for subjective questions, to avoid the degeneration of community standards. But you certainly can ask that sort of question here without being driven out of town. And if you get any grief, just link them here.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer!  I just want to be clear though.  Are you saying that my question belongs on SQAT, or SQAT-Meta?  (and is it ok to use the someone suggestive acronym SQAT?)

Comment: To be crystal clear, the question should be asked on the [SQA site.](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) The SQA Meta site is for questions that are about the SQA site, not SQA questions themselves.

Comment: Coolio.  Thought so, but just wanted to be Crystal myself, LOL.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Definitely ask them here, in the SQA (note SQA Meta site).   When you start getting into code and implementation, you might get faster answers from one of the coding sites, depending upon language and framework.